How do I always go to choose startup disk screen?
On my 2021 M1 iMac, how do I make it so that I go to the startup disk screen every time I boot my Mac?

Which year or model is your iMac?

It is a 2021 M1 iMac

there isn’t a built-in way to do this
Assuming you are running macOS, a way to script your next desired startdisk:
sudo systemsetup -setstartupdisk /path/to/startup/disk
sudo shutdown -r now

Or perhaps if older scripts to manage this fail, use Apple’s “authorized” restart tool.
sudo fdesetup authrestart

Use mount to check your mount points
